# How to save a video from the web to my iPhone Camera Roll

Tags: iphone, video

I uploaded a video to the web and I want to save it to the Camera Roll. How can I do that? I first uploaded it to Youtube and then I tried to download it from bitdownloader.io but it only opens it on a new Safari window. Also, I have phone 4 so I'm kinda limited in options.

Comment: Can you save it on your Mac and then sync it to your iPhone via iTunes?

Comment: I have no Mac, I have windows. But I already solved this so thank you anyway.